# Как будет выглядеть регулярное выражение для русского слова с точкой и пробелом?

Tags: javascript

Как будет выглядеть регулярка проверки для любого русского слова, пробела и точки. Например

```
г. Санкт-Петербург
г. Москва
```

должны проходить.

Вот нашла если только русские буквы  и пробел. Как добавить еще точку - разделитель и дефис

```
/^[а-яА-ЯЁё\s\-]+$/i;
```

Comment: Добавьте код, как вы пытались решить данную задачу. И с какими ошибками столкнулись.

Comment: `для любого русского слова, пробела и точки`  - `г. Санкт-Петербург` уже не пройдет по указанным условиям, присутствует дефис.

Comment: _как добавить еще точку_ - как ни странно, но нужно просто добавить `.` внутрь квадратных скобок

Comment: А вот был такой писатель О'Генри - это одно слово или два?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^[а-яё\-\. ]+$/i
```

Проверка регулярки https://regex101.com/r/oiNlcz/1

Comment: внутри квадратных скобок можно не экранировать точку, и минус, если он стоит последним

Comment: @Grundy, а я хочу экранировать :Р

Comment: Экранирую что хочу, законом не запрещено? :-D

Comment: @Grundy, а черточка тут не последняя, а по середине ;)

Comment: а я про последнюю :)